# Comment utiliser « que »

Tags: grammaire

> Malheureusement, nous travaillons sur tout le cercle ou ne pouvons tout simplement pas l'habitude de dire que nous allons travailler **que** sur une partie de celui-ci.

« Que » est il nécessaire dans cette phrase ?

Comment: I suggest you give a translation in English of what you want to say. I am afraid your sentence is rather difficult to understand...

Comment: As a French person, I don't understand your sentence.

Comment: L'_all around approach_ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part is confusing (you used the wrong verb or you forgot to add one, we can't tell), but the last part is pretty understandable to me.

In this case, **que** means **only**.

I modified your sentence to translate it, without changing the part you asked about :

> *Nous disons que nous allons travailler que sur une partie de celui-ci [du cercle].*
>
> We're saying that we will work **only** on a part of it.
>
> We're saying that we will **just** work on a part of it.

That's what I think the last part of the sentence means.

Answer (score 1):

In french, words repetition isn't really appreciated. In your case, you can replace your **que**  by **seulement**.

But your sentence's still incorrect.

I think what you are trying to say is something similar to this :

> Malheureusement, nous travaillons sur tout le cercle. Nous n'avons
>   tout simplement pas l'habitude dire que nous allons travailler seulement sur une
>   partie de celui-ci.

or

> Malheureusement, nous travaillons sur tout le cercle. Pouvons-nous
>   tout simplement dire que nous allons travailler seulement sur une
>   partie de celui-ci?

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence is ungrammatical in several places and I don't understand what you're trying to say.

> nous travaillons sur tout le cercle

“We work on the whole circle”. Ok, fine.

> ou

This means “or”. I don't see how this can tie the two halves of the sentence. If you meant “where”, it's spelled *où*, but the sentence doesn't make sense either.

> [nous] ne pouvons tout simplement pas l'habitude de dire que …

There's either a missing word or a wrong word. “*[Nous]* ne pouvons” means “we cannot”, which cannot have “*l'habitude” (“the habit”) as a direct complement. If you mean “we aren't used to saying …”, it would be “*nous n'avons pas l'habitude de dire …*”.

> nous allons travailler sur une partie de celui-ci.

“we will work on part of it”. Ok.

If you want to say “we will **only** work on part of it”, that's “*nous **n'**allons travailler **que** sur une partie de celui-ci*”. You can omit *ne* (spelled *n'* in front of a vowel) in colloquial speech, but not in written French.